# How to fetch Parent Process Id on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, pid

Is there an API in the C++ (or STL) to fetch the parent process id? if not then what could be the portable code to do so?
I understand there linux api such as getppid can do the job on unix platforms but what is equivalent of the same on windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Libraries such as Qt and boost can achieve your goal in a cross-platform manner. In the boost case, here is information about the process class: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/reference/classboost_1_1process_1_1process.html

Comment: However, Boost.Process is not (yet) an official Boost C++ library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following links will hep you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9893/Get-Parent-Process-PID

https://gist.github.com/253013/d47b90159cf8ffa4d92448614b748aa1d235ebe4

Comment: Thanks Phoenix, it worked! However I was curious to know this code would work on the Windows64 as well?

Comment: change the build configuration to 64 bit(default is all computers) and check if it builds successfully.