# How to get conhost.exe process id?

Tags: delphi, winapi, freepascal, windows-console

After doing some research and looking at the source code of ProcessHacker, it seems the way to obtain conhost.exe's process id is to use NtQuerySystemInformation.

I wrote the following little program for testing purposes but, it isn't working and I don't see why.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}

program _QueryInformationProcess_ProcessConsoleHostProcess;

uses
  Windows,
  sysutils
  ;

{$ifdef VER90}
type
  ptrint  = longint;
  ptruint = DWORD;

const
  DELETE                   = $00010000;
  READ_CONTROL             = $00020000;
  WRITE_DAC                = $00040000;
  WRITE_OWNER              = $00080000;
  SYNCHRONIZE              = $00100000;

  STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = $000F0000;

  STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ     = READ_CONTROL;
  STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE    = READ_CONTROL;
  STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE  = READ_CONTROL;

  STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL      = $001F0000;
  SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL      = $0000FFFF;

  PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS        = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or SYNCHRONIZE or $FFF;
{$endif}

const
  ntdll = 'ntdll.dll';

  { process information class(es) used in QueryInformationProcess             }

type
  PROCESSINFOCLASS =
  (
    {  0 }  ProcessBasicInformation,                      // q: PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION
    {  1 }  ProcessQuotaLimits,                           // qs: QUOTA_LIMITS, QUOTA_LIMITS_EX
    {  2 }  ProcessIoCounters,                            // q: IO_COUNTERS
    {  3 }  ProcessVmCounters,                            // q: VM_COUNTERS, VM_COUNTERS_EX, VM_COUNTERS_EX2
    {  4 }  ProcessTimes,                                 // q: KERNEL_USER_TIMES
    {  5 }  ProcessBasePriority,                          // s: KPRIORITY
    {  6 }  ProcessRaisePriority,                         // s: ULONG
    {  7 }  ProcessDebugPort,                             // q: HANDLE
    {  8 }  ProcessExceptionPort,                         // s: HANDLE
    {  9 }  ProcessAccessToken,                           // s: PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN
    { 10 }  ProcessLdtInformation,                        // qs: PROCESS_LDT_INFORMATION                                                               // 10
    { 11 }  ProcessLdtSize,                               // s: PROCESS_LDT_SIZE
    { 12 }  ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode,                  // qs: ULONG
    { 13 }  ProcessIoPortHandlers,                        // (kernel-mode only)
    { 14 }  ProcessPooledUsageAndLimits,                  // q: POOLED_USAGE_AND_LIMITS
    { 15 }  ProcessWorkingSetWatch,                       // q: PROCESS_WS_WATCH_INFORMATION[]; s: void
    { 16 }  ProcessUserModeIOPL,
    { 17 }  ProcessEnableAlignmentFaultFixup,             // s: BOOLEAN
    { 18 }  ProcessPriorityClass,                         // qs: PROCESS_PRIORITY_CLASS
    { 19 }  ProcessWx86Information,
    { 20 }  ProcessHandleCount,                           // q: ULONG, PROCESS_HANDLE_INFORMATION                                                               // 20
    { 21 }  ProcessAffinityMask,                          // s: KAFFINITY
    { 22 }  ProcessPriorityBoost,                         // qs: ULONG
    { 23 }  ProcessDeviceMap,                             // qs: PROCESS_DEVICEMAP_INFORMATION, PROCESS_DEVICEMAP_INFORMATION_EX
    { 24 }  ProcessSessionInformation,                    // q: PROCESS_SESSION_INFORMATION
    { 25 }  ProcessForegroundInformation,                 // s: PROCESS_FOREGROUND_BACKGROUND
    { 26 }  ProcessWow64Information,                      // q: ULONG_PTR
    { 27 }  ProcessImageFileName,                         // q: UNICODE_STRING
    { 28 }  ProcessLUIDDeviceMapsEnabled,                 // q: ULONG
    { 29 }  ProcessBreakOnTermination,                    // qs: ULONG
    { 30 }  ProcessDebugObjectHandle,                     // q: HANDLE                                                               // 30
    { 31 }  ProcessDebugFlags,                            // qs: ULONG
    { 32 }  ProcessHandleTracing,                         // q: PROCESS_HANDLE_TRACING_QUERY; s: size 0 disables, otherwise enables
    { 33 }  ProcessIoPriority,                            // qs: IO_PRIORITY_HINT
    { 34 }  ProcessExecuteFlags,                          // qs: ULONG
    { 35 }  ProcessResourceManagement,
    { 36 }  ProcessCookie,                                // q: ULONG
    { 37 }  ProcessImageInformation,                      // q: SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION
    { 38 }  ProcessCycleTime,                             // q: PROCESS_CYCLE_TIME_INFORMATION                                                               // since VISTA
    { 39 }  ProcessPagePriority,                          // q: ULONG
    { 40 }  ProcessInstrumentationCallback,               // 40
    { 41 }  ProcessThreadStackAllocation,                 // s: PROCESS_STACK_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION, PROCESS_STACK_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION_EX
    { 42 }  ProcessWorkingSetWatchEx,                     // q: PROCESS_WS_WATCH_INFORMATION_EX[]
    { 43 }  ProcessImageFileNameWin32,                    // q: UNICODE_STRING
    { 44 }  ProcessImageFileMapping,                      // q: HANDLE (input)
    { 45 }  ProcessAffinityUpdateMode,                    // qs: PROCESS_AFFINITY_UPDATE_MODE
    { 46 }  ProcessMemoryAllocationMode,                  // qs: PROCESS_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_MODE
    { 47 }  ProcessGroupInformation,                      // q: USHORT[]
    { 48 }  ProcessTokenVirtualizationEnabled,            // s: ULONG
    { 49 }  ProcessConsoleHostProcess,                    // q: ULONG_PTR
    { 50 }  ProcessWindowInformation,                     // q: PROCESS_WINDOW_INFORMATION                                                               // 50
    { 51 }  ProcessHandleInformation,                     // q: PROCESS_HANDLE_SNAPSHOT_INFORMATION                                                               // since WIN8
    { 52 }  ProcessMitigationPolicy,                      // s: PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION
    { 53 }  ProcessDynamicFunctionTableInformation,
    { 54 }  ProcessHandleCheckingMode,
    { 55 }  ProcessKeepAliveCount,                        // q: PROCESS_KEEPALIVE_COUNT_INFORMATION
    { 56 }  ProcessRevokeFileHandles,                     // s: PROCESS_REVOKE_FILE_HANDLES_INFORMATION
    { 57 }  ProcessWorkingSetControl,                     // s: PROCESS_WORKING_SET_CONTROL
    { 58 }  ProcessHandleTable,                           // since WINBLUE
    { 59 }  ProcessCheckStackExtentsMode,
    { 60 }  ProcessCommandLineInformation,                // q: UNICODE_STRING                                                               // 60
    { 61 }  ProcessProtectionInformation,                 // q: PS_PROTECTION
    { 62 }  ProcessMemoryExhaustion,                      // PROCESS_MEMORY_EXHAUSTION_INFO                                                               // since THRESHOLD
    { 63 }  ProcessFaultInformation,                      // PROCESS_FAULT_INFORMATION
    { 64 }  ProcessTelemetryIdInformation,                // PROCESS_TELEMETRY_ID_INFORMATION
    { 65 }  ProcessCommitReleaseInformation,              // PROCESS_COMMIT_RELEASE_INFORMATION
    { 66 }  ProcessDefaultCpuSetsInformation,
    { 67 }  ProcessAllowedCpuSetsInformation,
    { 68 }  ProcessReserved1Information,
    { 69 }  ProcessReserved2Information,
    { 70 }  ProcessSubsystemProcess,                      // 70
    { 71 }  ProcessJobMemoryInformation,                  // PROCESS_JOB_MEMORY_INFO
    { 72 }  ProcessInPrivate,                             // since THRESHOLD2
    { 73 }  ProcessRaiseUMExceptionOnInvalidHandleClose,
    { 74 }  MaxProcessInfoClass
  );

type
  NTSTATUS                    = DWORD;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle            : THANDLE;
                                   ProcessInformationClass  : DWORD;
                                   ProcessInformation       : pointer;
                                   ProcessInformationLength : DWORD;
                                   ReturnLength             : PDWORD)
         : NTSTATUS; stdcall; external ntdll;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure EndProgram(ExitCode : ptruint);
begin
  writeln('Exit code : ', ExitCode);
  writeln('Press <enter>/<return> to end this program.');

  readln;
end;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

var
  ProcessHandle      : THANDLE;

  ReturnLength       : DWORD;
  NtResult           : NTSTATUS;

  { upon success should contain the conhost.exe process id                    }

  ConsoleHostProcess : ptruint;

begin
  writeln;

  writeln('GetCurrentProcessId : ', GetCurrentProcessId()); { not conhost's   }

  // since we are dealing with our own process we can specify PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS

  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
                               FALSE,
                               GetCurrentProcessId());

  if ProcessHandle = 0 then EndProgram(1);


  // use the process handle to obtain conhost.exe process id

  ReturnLength := 0;  { for good measure }
  NtResult     := 0;

  NtResult := NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle,
                                        DWORD(ProcessConsoleHostProcess),
                                        @ConsoleHostProcess,
                                        sizeof(ConsoleHostProcess),
                                        nil);
                                        //@ReturnLength);

  { returns 0xC0000003 STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS                              }
  { [Invalid Parameter] The specified information class is not a valid        }
  { information class for the specified object.                               }

  writeln('NTSTATUS           : ', IntToHex(NtResult, 0));
  writeln('ReturnLength       : ', ReturnLength);

  writeln;
  writeln('Press <enter>/<result> to end this program.');
  readln;
end.
```

As is stated in the program comments, I get NTSTATUS - 0xC0000003 STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS

which means:

[Invalid Parameter] The specified information class is not a valid information class for the specified object.

but, I don't see it, where is my mistake ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: On a side note, you can and should use `GetCurrentProcess()` instead of `OpenProcess(GetCurrentProcessId())`

Comment: @ Remy, yes, you're right.  The reason the example uses GetCurrentProcessId is because I'm actually using that method with processes other than mine and, what I have is their process id.  I was trying to make the example as close as possible to what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) under `Parameters, ProcessInformationClass` . `ProcessConsoleHostProcess` is not listed as a valid parameter.

Comment: @ Tom, it's not documented.  ProcessHacker and Process Explorer use it.

Comment: Debug the working code and see where it diverges from your code

Comment: @ David, I've been trying to do that.  I cannot get ProcessHacker to compile anymore and I no longer have a debug version of the executable.  Some update to VS2107 messed everything up.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to debug the entire program. Just extract the part that is of interest.

Comment: this is `ProcessOwnerInformation` (49) declared in *ntddk.h*, what is windows version you use ?

Comment: @ RbMm, sorry for the delay in responding to you.  I got the definition from ProcessHacker's ntpsapi.h, specifically, the structure typedef enum _PROCESSINFOCLASS.  Since that works for ProcessHacker, it should work for other programs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that parameter `ProcessConsoleHostProcess(49)` is not support in 32-bit, and I can just get it work in 64-bit program. You could try to compile it with x64.

There are also reminders in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess#remarks)

> To maintain the compatibility of your application, it is better to use
>   public functions mentioned in the description of the
>   ProcessInformationClass parameter instead.

Or you could also get it in another way with [Tool Help Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/tool-help-functions). Here is the related [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102238/c-how-do-i-get-the-current-console-conhost-process).

Comment: @ Drake, I've tried in 64bit and I get the same result, STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS.  Do you have a working example you'd be willing to share ?

Comment: @ScienceAmateur This is [sample](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AuuE71XVcHDogwBS9LQ13PClVCtq) for C++ project.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur pay attention to the type of parameters, `sizeof(ConsoleHostProcess)` should be `8` in 64-bit.

Comment: @ Drake, thank you very much.  That was really very helpful.